# Ensuring user input is an integer in a range

Tags: c#, validation, console, comparative-review

I have isolated a little bit of code that was causing a small debate between myself and another user.  I have taken some of the things that he said and meshed it with the code that was being reviewed in the first place [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36482/18427).

**Original Code**

> ```
> while (!validInput)
> {
>     var playerChoice = -1;
>     Console.WriteLine("Please choose your Gesture ");
>     gameSetup(listOfGestures);
>     try
>     {
>         playerChoice = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
>     }
>     catch (FormatException e)
>     {
>         validInput = false;
>     }
>
>     if (playerChoice > 0 && playerChoice <= listOfGestures.Count)
>     {
>         playerGesture = listOfGestures[playerChoice - 1];
>         validInput = true;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         validInput = false;
>     }
> }
> ```

---

Here is what I came up with based on our [conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13448/loops).

**New Code**

```
var validInput = false; //forgot this part
while (!validInput)
{
    var playerChoice = -1;
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose your Gesture ");
    gameSetup(listOfGestures);
    validInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out playerChoice);
    if (playerChoice > 0 && playerChoice <= listOfGestures.Count)
    {
        playerGesture = listOfGestures[playerChoice - 1];
        validInput = true;
    }
}
```

---

Do I need to create a new method to sort out user input and whether or not it is an integer inside the min and max bounds?

Comment: You initialize `playerChoice` to `-1`, but that value is never used.

Comment: `validInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out playerChoice);` @CodesInChaos

Comment: That line overwrites the initial value of player choice and doesn't read it (it's an `out` parameter), so you didn't need to initialize it to `-1`. I'd instead declare it as `int playerChoice;` without initialization.

Comment: why not `var playerChoice`?

Comment: Unless you REALLY need to use an untyped variable, strongly typing generally is the better way to go, because it can help catch stupid errors down the line. It's an added line of defence against bugs.

Comment: This is C#, there are no untyped variables. All variables are strongly statically typed.

Comment: I thought that the `out` parameter takes in a variable that is already in scope into the function and returns it with the value it is given inside the function, is that correct?

Comment: Malachi, you're right about the out parameter, but the variable it takes in doesn't need to be initialized. Initializing it in that line reduces readability a bit because it makes it look like that value will be used for something

Comment: but it is being used for something....@BenAaronson I am a little lost I think. are you saying that I don't need to create the variable ahead of time,  that playerChoice can be created right there?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The second sample is definitely better. I would be inclined to continue to improve the code by **separating mechanisms from policies**. The *policy* is the code that actually expresses the *meaning* of the program; the *mechanism* is the code that expresses *what specific operations implement the policy*.

This idea comes from security design; you don't want the code that computes "is Bob allowed to open this door?" and the code that computes "is that really Bob's card key?" to be the same code. The first is a policy, the second is a mechanism. But it applies generally to all code.

By separating mechanism from policy we enable both to be understood more easily. The "main line" of your code should read like the specification. If you had to describe your code in English you'd probably say something like "present the user with a choice of gestures. If the user chooses an invalid gesture, keep trying until they choose a valid gesture."  That's the *meaning* of your program, but that's not what your code looks like. Rather, your code looks like the most important things in the world are integer and bool variables, list counts, and so on.

Let's identify a mechanism: parsing an integer and testing whether it is in range is the *mechanism* behind the *policy* of "the user must choose a valid gesture". So let's isolate that mechanism into a *purely* mechanistic method, that knows *nothing* about your policy domain:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static int? BoundedParse(this string str, int lower, int upper)
    {
        if (str == null) 
            return null;
        int result;
        bool success;
        success = int.TryParse(str, out result);
        if (!success) 
            return null;
        if (result < lower) 
            return null;
        if (result > upper) 
            return null;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Let's now rewrite your loop as a do-while instead of a while. Look how much ugly mechanism we removed, leaving your policy shining brightly through:

```
gameSetup(listOfGestures);
int? choice;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose your Gesture ");
    choice = Console.ReadLine().BoundedParse(1, listofGestures.Count);
}
while(choice == null);
playerGesture = listOfGestures[choice.Value - 1];
```

And as a bonus, we now have a reusable method that we can apply to *any* task that requires that a string be parsed as a bounded integer.

We can take this even further. Isn't that loop a mechanism? Move it into a helper method:

```
static int PromptForNumber(string prompt, int lower, int upper)
{
    int? choice;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        choice = Console.ReadLine().BoundedParse(lower, upper);
    }
    while(choice == null);
    return choice.Value;
}
```

And now your method is:

```
gameSetup(listOfGestures);
int choice = PromptForNumber("Please choose your gesture", 1, listofGestures.Count);
playerGesture = listOfGestures[choice - 1];
```

Now the code is super clear what is going on *at the policy level* because all the stuff you don't care about is now the responsibility of some mechanism somewhere. (And again we have a great mechanism for prompting for a number that we can re-use later.)

Even better: maybe there is a better way to display a prompt and get a number. If we decided that we wanted to write a GUI instead, we can change the mechanism code without changing the policy code. The policy code doesn't care *how* the valid gesture gets chosen, just that it does.

Comment: Very well explained, puts the ideas of encapsulation and separation of responsibility into more concrete terms that others can more readily understand.

Comment: I generally don't like `do while` loops I rather like `while` loops. I guess that I could still write it as a `while` loop.  I will post the code to the game when I am finished with my changes.

Comment: I know leaving "+1" and "thanks" comments are generally discouraged, but I want to ignore that here just to say thanks, Eric, for all of your answers across Stack Exchange.  I regularly browse through the latest answers on your profile (mainly on SO), because the quality of the information that you provide is always so good.

Comment: @JohnH: That discouragement is in my opinion counterproductive. Politeness costs very little and goes a long way towards making people feel good about both asking for help and providing help to others. You're very welcome; it's my pleasure. Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: @EricLippert, I have posted new code [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44034/18427) I used some of the code you provided word for word and other code that you provided I altered. would you mind looking at my code there and letting me know what you think. please keep in mind I was posting it at 1:30 A.M. (should be good if programmers do their best work in the middle of the night, we will see)

Comment: Commentators please don't overlook the other answers, they are good answers as well.

Comment: @JohnH: "+1" and "thanks" **answers** are against the policy of the network, with the instruction to leave a comment instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt Clicking the `add comment` link below yours, without typing anything in the textbox, displays the following message: `Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.  Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".`

Comment: @EricLippert "Thanks — good point about _X_" comments are fine; just "Thanks" would be noise. Votes are the currency of thanks that makes Stack Exchange sites work, so we prefer voting — it's the most rewarding form of thanks possible. I notice that you have only voted twice so far. Code Review would benefit greatly from having experts like you recognize good questions and answers from other members by voting.

Answer (score 12):

#### Random Nitpicks

- `validInput` should be named `isValidInput` to follow `bool` naming convention.
- `listOfGestures` shouldn't convey its type in the name (assuming it's a `List<Gesture>`); `gestures` would be a better name.
- if `gestures` were a `Dictionary<int,Gesture>`, your *check-if-the-value-is-within-bounds* condition would become much simpler: `gestures.TryGetValue(playerChoice, out playerGesture);`

> *Do I need to create a new method to sort out user input and whether or not it is an integer inside the min and max bounds?*

If you went OOP-all-the-way and encapsulated that piece of logic into its own object, you could write a unit test that validates whether a valid input returns a `Gesture`:

```
interface IGestureInputValidator
{
    Gesture ValidateInput(string userInput);
}
```

The implementation of that interface could return `null` for any illegal `userInput` value, or a `Gesture` instance for any legal input. This would change your code a little:

```
Gesture playerGesture;
while (playerGesture == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose your Gesture:");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    playerGesture = _validator.ValidateInput(input);
}
```

Notice `_validator` is an instance field; you can probably *inject* that instance in your constructor (or `new` it up there).

---

I... just noticed you have no `Gesture` object - a `string` could work just as well:

```
string playerGesture;
while (playerGesture == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose your Gesture:");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    playerGesture = _validator.ValidateInput(input);
}
```

Given a small change in the validator interface:

```
interface IGestureInputValidator
{
    string ValidateInput(string userInput);
}
```

However I don't like this, because the intent isn't crystal-clear anymore; a `string` could be anything, and we're looking for a *specific kind of string*. I think gestures deserve their own class, or even better, an enum. Whatever you do, extracting the validation into its own object (or method, if you consider that responsibility as part of the same class that holds the other piece of logic) allows you to change that logic, without affecting the rest of your code.

I'd recommend to *separate the concerns* as much as possible, so to boldly answer your question, yes, you should separate it.

Comment: In one case, you're telling him to use a naming convention for bool that indicates the type, in another case you're advising him not to indicate in the name that his variable is a list. Isn't that inconsistent?

Comment: @NateC-K a `bool` is a simple value type with true/false values; "IsXxxxxx" is an established naming convention for them. A *list*, however, is a reference type that implements an interface; by sticking "List" to a variable's name, you are potentially calling a cat as a dog, ...or a lion. Many types implement `IList<T>`, not just `List<T>`; calling an enumerable a xxxxList is a lie.

Comment: The "is..." naming convention is part of Hungarian notation, which MS says you shouldn't bother with anymore. Anything that implements IList is necessarily an IList (not to mention a variable of this type can only be used to call methods that implement IList), so I don't see how you can say that it is "a lie" to call it a list. You program only cares about the typing of the variable at the current level of abstraction; you seem to suggest that I should care about the details underlying the abstraction even when they are irrelevant.

Comment: My main point, though, is that you are advocating for a naming convention in one case and against in another case. Personally I'm against any kind of type-based naming convention when we're using a language like C# that makes it unnecessary, but sometimes it's still helpful to include some type information in a name.

Comment: Variable naming is for the Developer only, the compiler will compile the code no matter what you name it.  standards are for people maintaining the code.  the naming schemes are there as guidelines.

Comment: @NateC-K From Microsoft's [Names of Type Members (4.5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx): "1. DO name collection properties with a _plural phrase_ describing the items in the collection _instead of_ using a singular phrase followed by "List" or "Collection." 2. DO name Boolean properties with an affirmative phrase (CanSeek instead of CantSeek). _Optionally, you can also prefix Boolean properties with "Is," "Can," or "Has," but only where it adds value._"

Answer (score 11):

It would be best for the sake of modularity, and re-usability for this whole chunk of code to be placed in a separate method. If you are going to need more user input besides just what gesture they want to use you could also make it more generic to be re-used through the rest of your program for various situations.

Your code seems to be a bit illogical as you are using the `playerChoice` variable even when you know it was not parsed correctly. you set `validInput`, but then don't check it in the if statement.

Here is how I would re-write that chunk if you weren't going to just separate it all out into a generic method of its own.

**Note**: I also changed the default value of `playerChoice` to be 0 because that is obviously out of range in this case, as you say that valid input has to be over 0. This change is minor and unnecessary, but I just wanted you to be aware of it.

```
while (!validInput)
{
    var playerChoice = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose your Gesture ");
    gameSetup(listOfGestures);
    if (validInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out playerChoice) && playerChoice > 0 && playerChoice <= listOfGestures.Count)
        playerGesture = listOfGestures[playerChoice - 1];
}
```

---

**Edit**: My [original response](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43654/38054) to the overall structure of this program included code that gave the user specific feedback to tell the user why their input was wrong (Point # 9 in my review). If you are not looking for such feedback in a method, here is a simple Method that gets Integer User input from the console

```
public static int GetIntInRange(int min = int.MinValue, int max = int.MaxValue, string prompt = "Please enter an Integer: ")
{
    int parsedValue;
    do { Console.Write(prompt); } 
    while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out parsedValue) && parsedValue >= min && parsedValue <= max));
    return parsedValue;
}
```

Comment: Good, but your code has the bug that inputting `0` or a number higher than the number of gestures will still end the loop.  Which is, admittedly, a bug in the original code too, but it was more obvious there.

Comment: @Bobson I'm not sure I see the problem, if the user enters 0 it will fail `playerChoice > 0`  which will set `validInput` to false, which will cause the main loop to go again.

Comment: Ooh, no, you're right.  I misplaced the `()`'s when I was reading it such that `validInput` was only set to the result of `TryParse()` and not the rest of the conditions.

Comment: @Bobson it was a flaw in my code, and Ben's code would fix that.

Comment: @BenVlodgi will `playerChoice` be assigned before the rest of the comparisons in the `if` statement?

Comment: @Malachi yes, everything happens sequentially, so the comparisons will only be ran if the `TryParse` didn't fail. the `TryParse`has to finish to be able to determine this, which means it has sent out the `playerChoice` before continuing.

Comment: I think it makes the code harder to read if you cram so much of the logic into the test part of the do-while block. I think it's generally better practice to put things like reading input inside the body of the loop, assuming that doing so gives you the same result.

Comment: @NateC-K There is an expanded version of the code I just edited in, but I'm a minimalist, I love making code as concise as possible, the expanded version required the declaration of another variable and was many more lines of code. In my own code, I may break the while statement into multiple lines if it got too confusing.

Comment: I agree that adding some line breaks would go a long way toward making the code clearer.