# RPSLS game revisited. Is my design better than previous attempts?

Tags: c#, game, community-challenge, rock-paper-scissors

This question is a follow up to these questions:

1. [RPSLS Game in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36482/18427)
2. [Ensuring user input is an integer in a range](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/43965/18427)
3. [RPSLS is less messy now, but is it clean?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44034/18427)

Right now I have a couple of ideas in the think tank about how I want to code what I like to call "killMessage" the whole process seems a little intimidating at the moment, in other words I haven't decided exactly how it is going to work out yet.

There is plenty of code that I borrowed/altered/stole from other answers, but I think we all assumed that was going to happen a little bit, and I think that I understand most of what I included, so I still learned something from it and didn't just copy pasta in the code.

I really like the idea of a Gesture class so that I can actually give the Gesture abilities.

```
/// <summary>
/// Thanks to 
/// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/38054/benvlodgi
/// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/4318/eric-lippert
/// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug
/// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/30346/chriswue
/// </summary>
namespace RPSLSGame
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            /* Here are your rules: 
            "Scissors cuts paper, 
            paper covers rock, 
            rock crushes lizard, 
            lizard poisons Spock, 
            Spock smashes scissors, 
            scissors decapitate lizard, 
            lizard eats paper, 
            paper disproves Spock, 
            Spock vaporizes rock. 
            And as it always has, rock crushes scissors." 
            -- Dr. Sheldon Cooper */
            int win = 0;
            int lose = 0;
            int tie = 0;

            IList<Gesture> gameGestures = GetGestures();

            do{
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose your Gesture ");
                PrintMenu(gameGestures);
                var playerGesture = gameGestures[PromptForNumber("Please choose your gesture",1,gameGestures.Count)-1];
                var computerPlay = GetRandomOption(gameGestures);

                Console.WriteLine ("Computer: " + computerPlay);
                Console.WriteLine ("your Gesture: " + playerGesture);

                if (playerGesture.Equals(computerPlay)){
                    tie++;
                }else if(playerGesture.Defeats(computerPlay)){
                    win++;
                }else{
                    lose++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine ("Your Score is (W:L:T:) : {0}:{1}:{2}", win, lose, tie);
                if (Choice("Would you like to reset your score?"))
                {
                    win = 0;
                    lose=0;
                    tie=0;
                }
            }while (Choice("Would you like to play again? Y/N"));
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
            Console.ReadLine ();
        } 

        public static void DecideWinner ()
        {
            //TODO: Create Method for Deciding the Winner.
            //I still need to move the decision logic here. 
            //but it won't be as big as I thought it was going to be
        }

        static int PromptForNumber (string prompt, int lower, int upper)
        {
            int? pick = null;
            while (pick == null) {
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                pick = Console.ReadLine().BoundedParse (lower, upper);
            }
            return pick.Value;
        }

        public static void PrintMenu (List<string> List)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<List.Count; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine ((i+1) + ": " + List[i]);
            }       
        }

        public static void PrintMenu (IList<Gesture> GestureList)
        {
            for (int i=0; i < GestureList.Count; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine ((i + 1) + ": " + GestureList [i]);
            }
        }

        public static string GetRandomOption (List<string> options)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            return options[rand.Next(0,options.Count)];
        }

        public static Gesture GetRandomOption (IList<Gesture> options)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            return options[rand.Next (0,options.Count)];
        }

        public static Boolean Choice (string prompt)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (prompt);
                switch (Console.ReadKey (true).Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.Y:
                    {
                        Console.Write ("Y\n"); 
                        return true;
                    }
                    case ConsoleKey.N:
                    {
                        Console.Write ("N\n");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

/// <summary>
/// This is some code that I borrowed from 
/// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/14749/peter-kiss
/// from an answer that he gave to one of my Questions, the answer has since been deleted.
/// </summary>

        static IList<Gesture> GetGestures()
        {
            var spock = new Gesture("Spock");
            var lizard = new Gesture("Lizard");
            var paper = new Gesture("Paper");
            var rock = new Gesture("Rock");
            var scissors = new Gesture("Scissors");

            spock.AddDefeats(new[] { scissors, rock });
            lizard.AddDefeats(new[] { paper, spock });
            paper.AddDefeats(new[] { rock, spock });
            rock.AddDefeats(new[] { lizard, scissors });
            scissors.AddDefeats(new[] { paper, lizard });

            var gestures = new List<Gesture> {rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock};
            gestures.ForEach(x => x.Seal());
            return gestures;
        }
    }

    public class Gesture
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }

        private HashSet<Gesture> _defeats = new HashSet<Gesture>();
        private bool _isSealed;
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Gesture(string name)
        {
            if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
            Name = name;
        }

        public void Seal()
        {
            _isSealed = true;
        }

        public void AddDefeats(IEnumerable<Gesture> defeats)
        {
            if (_isSealed)
            {
                throw new Exception("Gesture is sealed");
            }

            foreach (var gesture in defeats)
            {
                _defeats.Add(gesture);
            }
        }

        //public void AddKillMessage(Tuple<Gesture,Gesture,string>  
        public void AddKillMessage (Dictionary<Dictionary<Gesture,Gesture>,string> killMessage)
        {
            if (_isSealed) {
                throw new Exception ("Gesture is Sealed");
            }
        }

        protected bool Equals(Gesture other)
        {
            return string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Gesture) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public bool Defeats(Gesture gesture)
        {
            return _defeats.Any(x => x.Equals(gesture));
        }
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static int? BoundedParse (this string str, int lower, int upper)
    {
        int result;
        bool success;
        success = int.TryParse (str, out result);
        if (!(lower <= result && result <= upper) || (!success) || (str == null)){
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I hope that repeat reviewers find that I have taken their advice to heart and hopefully I haven't slaughtered their code while making it my own.

There are several overloaded methods in the code that I left there from previous iterations.

Comment: I did fail to mention that I gave in to peer pressure and used a do while loop for my main loop. Any feed back on that is also welcome, please also let me know what you think I am doing right as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to leave a broader review to other answers, and only focus on a single line of code:

> ```
> throw new Exception("Gesture is sealed");
> ```

Don't do that.

There are really two alternatives to throwing exceptions.

One is to throw an existing exception, **derived** from `System.Exception`. This is trickier than it sounds, because you need to pick your exception carefully - you want to throw a *meaningful* exception.

In this case an `InvalidOperationException` seems in line with the [*Principle of Least Astonishment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment):

> ## InvalidOperationException Class
>
> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.
>   <sub>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx</sub>

There are a few exception subclasses like this one (and `ArgumentException` and its derivatives), that are very often the most meaningful and *written-for-that-purpose* exception to use.

---

Another way would be to define your own. That's easier that it sounds, you just derive a new class from `System.Exception`:

```
public class GestureSealedException : Exception
{
    public GestureSealedException()
        : base("Gesture is sealed.") { }
}
```

And now you can `throw` and `catch` a `GestureSealedException`.

---

#### That said...

> *Don't throw `System.Exception`.*

In my quick research for why that class wasn't `abstract` in the first place if it wasn't intended to be instanciated and thrown, I found an interesting [discussion on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119668/abstract-exception-super-type). Emphasis mine:

> *when coding **small demo apps** or **proof-of-concepts**, I don't want to start designing 10 different exception sub-classes, or **spending time** trying to decide which is the "best" exception class for the situation. I'd rather just throw Exception and pass a string that explains the details. When it's **throw-away code**, I don't care about these things [...]*
>
> <sub>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/119683/68834</sub>

The flipside of this out-of-context quote, is that when *it is* quality code, you *do* care about these things.

Comment: I like this answer, 1. I was using someone else's code there and should have changed that exception.  2. I have created exceptions before, but I need the practice. 3. not sure why I would use an exception there. I need to look into it more this coming week probably before(or while) I work on the KillMessages

Comment: @Malachi FYI, I've moved this answer [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44880/23788) as a canonical answer to *"Throwing System.Exception"*.

Comment: sounds good to me.

Answer (score 5):

1. In the scope of this program, there is no benefit to using a `Gesture` `class` vs using an `enum` with some extension methods. I will draw upon my latest version of an [OOP RPSLS](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44577/rpslsmb-oop-version-2) for some examples.

   Using a `Gesture` `enum`

   ```
   enum Gesture
   {
       Rock,
       Paper,
       Scissors,
       Lizard,
       Spock
   }
   ```

   You can easily add an extension method to give you the `Defeats` method you implemented in your `Gesture` `class`. Below I assume you have a Dictionary of Rules like in [my version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44577/rpslsmb-oop-version-2).

   ```
   public static class Extensions
   {
       public static bool Defeates(this Gesture me, Gesture gesture)
       {
           return Game.Rules[me].Item1.ContainsKey(gesture);
       }
   }
   ```
2. I see that you have a few duplicated functions which do the exact same thing, only.. with a different data type. This is a bit of a red flag. Instead in this case you should just make one method. The one that takes a list of strings. Then make a function to convert an IList to a List ... this is super simple

   ```
    myGestureList.select(g=>g.ToString()).ToList();
   ```

   Or, better yet... make a method that uses Generic T, then you can use PrintMenu GetRandomOption with any data type.

   ```
   public static T GetRandomOption<T>(List<T> options)
   {
       return options[new Random().Next(0, options.Count)];
   }
   ```

   Now whenever you call this method the type `T` will be inferred from the type of `List` you pass in and will result with that type of `object` being returned. I also in-lined the declaration of your `Random` `object` with the call of its `Next` method.

   Using this same technique, your PrintMenu Function will look like this (I think you should call this `PrintOptions`).

   ```
   public static void PrintMenu<T>(List<T> List)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + ": " + List[i]);
       }
   }
   ```

   Here is re-worked version of this code, which makes it easy to offset the base number if desired.

   ```
   public static void PrintMenu<T>(List<T> values, int baseIndex = 0)
   {
       values.ForEach(value => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", baseIndex++, value));
   }
   ```
3. Your win/lose/tie variables should be plural.

   ```
   int wins = 0;
   int loses = 0;
   int ties = 0;
   ```
4. In your Choice Function you should take off the brackets from your case statements.

   ```
   switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
   {
       case ConsoleKey.Y:
           Console.Write("Y\n");
           return true;
       case ConsoleKey.N:
           Console.Write("N\n");
           return false;
   }
   ```
5. In C# the convention is different than Java where you are encouraged to add your brackets at the end of a statement.. ie.

   ```
   if(Boolean value){
       statement;
   }
   ```

   Your if-else chain should not use that convention. And really you could just not have the brackets at all considering they are 1 liners. I wouldn't even be opposed to 1-lining each of these statements. This point is a little more opinion based, but that is the C# convention. If you just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in Visual Studio, you will find that your code will be reformatted to expand those brackets (only works if your code has no errors).

   ```
   if (playerGesture.Equals(computerPlay))
       tie++;
   else if(playerGesture.Defeats(computerPlay))
       win++;
   else
       lose++;
   ```
6. You should use OO for players instead of for Gestures, you can see my [old review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44175/38054) for more info on that. Or look at my more recent [CR post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44577/rpslsmb-oop-version-2).
7. Anything else I would have pointed out, has already been said by [@Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug)

Comment: I completely disagree with #4 and #5.  you should use brackets where you can. this keeps your code neat and tidy. as far as stating it's C# convention, which convention are you referring to?

Comment: encapsulation begs to differ with you on creating Gesture Objects rather than creating Gesture Variables. Gestures have Properties associated with them, they should be objects and not variables.

Comment: @Malachi #4 is correct, you should use the curly braces to define a *scope* - the `case` blocks of a `switch` statement **do not** define a scope, by wrapping `case` blocks in curly braces you are introducing a scope there, which means each `case` can then define its own local variables, which smells. As for #5, it's also correct, you should spare "egyptian braces" for Java... but using them won't cause any harm (other than a future maintainer would probably *CSharpify* them - I know I would!)

Comment: @Mat'sMug ok I understand that.  but I still think that using the brackets on if statements and for loops is necessary, for loops for the reason you mention of scope, and if statements because it defines the ending of the code block, which also has scope, if you have more than one line isn't it mandatory to use brackets?

Comment: @Malachi indeed, `if (true) DoSomething();` is legal (same for a 1-liner loop), but for maintainability and readability purposes, it's recommended to **always** correctly scope these code blocks, i.e. *use them curly braces* and go `if (true) { DoSomething(); }`.

Comment: @Malachi "as far as stating it's C# convention, which convention are you referring to?" Visual studio IDE editor won't line your braces under the case: it will put the brace 4 spaces to the right of the case, and the code another 4 spaces to the right of that.

Comment: @Malachi in a case statement you should use use the `break` keyword to end your code for that specific case.

Comment: @Malachi Also... Gestures don't have properties associated with them, which is the reason why an enum works

Comment: they have a property that says what Gestures they beat and what Gestures they lose to. they also have specific kill messages that are not shared.  these things are properties specific to Gesture Objects

Comment: this "Gesture" kills this "Gesture" Vs. Rock smashes scissors "Gesture" Times

Comment: @Malachi maintain a list of rules, it is sooo much simpler than making a gigantic clunky Gesture class. Then just use an extension method as I did above.

Comment: @BenVlodgi, you speak of C# convention and then you go against OOP Principles because it is "clunky"?  Gesture is a class. a Rock is an object. a lizard is an object. a pair of scissors is an object. these are objects and not variables you can create an enumeration of these objects I suppose, but they are still objects.

Comment: @Malachi I'm not going against OOP principles by using an enum, even so, using OO is not a C# standard. It is a good practice. In your case, you're not even using OO properly, those objects are just encasing strings and maintaining a list of strings that they interact with. you shouldn't be using strings, you should be using enums... even if you were using Gesture objects, there should still be a gesture enums determining what kind of Gesture object that is.

Comment: @Malachi Gestures aren't necessarily a class (with associated behaviour). Instead they can be modelled as a mere value (i.e. as an enum), with "Rules" as a class (where 'rules' define the gesture-gesture interactions).

Comment: FWIW an enum is also an `object` :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug indeed.. I was just making a distinction between Malachi's  Gesture class and my Gesture enum :)

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand Enums, maybe that should be my next study subject

Comment: although you have really good information here,  this is more about how my structure doesn't look like your structure, and not so much if my structure is good....I don't know if that makes complete sense, but I like @Mat'sMug Answer a little bit better for this question, I still value your answer though.  I will be looking into Enums when I get back to this project.  Thank you

Comment: @Malachi its not that your strucutre is different than mine which is the problem. I think that you made design poor design choices. I happen to be pointing out what I believe the right choice to be, and that it is something that I have already implemented. Where proper use of a language is great when programming, but the design of your application is the most important part. If your programs structure is poorly designed it will become cumbersome, it will affect you at every stage of development, and be difficult to change once you decide to.

Comment: @BenVlodgi, I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

I find it a nuisance to define so many methods merely in order to override Equals.

Therefore I sometimes define and invoke a method named `Matches` instead.

Given that you only have one instance of each gesture, do you even need to define it? The default implementation of object.Equals is to call object.ReferenceEquals.

---

Your `Seal` functionality is ugly, for several reasons. Two alternatives:

- Define AddDefeats as private; create a static constructor of the Gesture class, and construct the list of Gesture instance in the static constructor (which can invoke the private method)

  ```
  class Gesture
  {
      internal static IList<Gesture> AllGestures;

      static Gesture
      {
          var spock = new Gesture("Spock");
          var lizard = new Gesture("Lizard");
          var paper = new Gesture("Paper");
          var rock = new Gesture("Rock");
          var scissors = new Gesture("Scissors");

          spock.AddDefeats(new[] { scissors, rock });
          lizard.AddDefeats(new[] { paper, spock });
          paper.AddDefeats(new[] { rock, spock });
          rock.AddDefeats(new[] { lizard, scissors });
          scissors.AddDefeats(new[] { paper, lizard });

          AllGestures = new List<Gesture> {rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock};
      }
  ```
- Remove the AddDefeats method, and pass the array of defeats as a parameter to the Gesture constructor (so that a Gesture instance is fully-constructed immediately)

  ```
  // defeats expressed using strings (gesture names) instead of Gesture instances
  // because we need to refer to gestures which haven't been constructed yet
  public Gesture(string name, IEnumerable<string> defeats)
  {
      if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
      Name = name;

      foreach (var gesture in defeats)
      {
          _defeats.Add(gesture);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: would you still feel this way if I made it possible for an admin user to create new Gestures from the console interface of the application? I mean for the Static Gesture Constructor?  little confused about the static constructor part as well.

Comment: I edited the answer to show an example of a static constructor.