# Thread-safe session manager

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, concurrency

Expected behavior of the code below:

- There will be one static `SessionManager` accessed by many threads.
- Multiple calls to `SessionManager.UseTheSession` for a given session ID must be processed on a first come first serve basis (similarly, calling `EndSession` should allow any currently executing `UseTheSession`'s to finish).
- The goal of the individual session locks is that a call to `SessionManager.UseTheSession` by one thread doesn't hold up another thread that is calling the same method with a different session ID.

Things I'm looking for input on are:

- Will this perform as expected.
- Does `sessions` need to be a `ConcurrentDictionary` or does a regular `Dictionary` work fine here since I'm locking any access of the one key.
- What's a good way to handle the memory leak that happens when I keep creating new locks but don't remove them for a given id after I stop using that it?

The code (runnable in Linqpad with the inclusion of the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace):

```
void Main()
{
    var sm = new SessionManager();

    Guid id = sm.StartSession();

    sm.UseTheSession(id).Dump();
    sm.UseTheSession(id).Dump();

    sm.EndSession(id);
}

public class SessionManager
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object> sessionLocks =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object>();

    private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ASession> sessions =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ASession>();

    public Guid StartSession()
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

        // Takes a sec to create the session.
        var session = new ASession(string.Format("Session {0}", id));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        if(!sessions.TryAdd(id, session))
            throw new Exception("Astronomically unlikely situation encountered.");

        return id;
    }

    public int UseTheSession(Guid id)
    {
        lock(this.GetSessionLocker(id))
        {
            ASession session;
            if(sessions.TryGetValue(id, out session))
            {
                return this.DoSomethingWithSession(session);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.format("Session with id {0} does not exist.",
                    id));
            }
        }
    }

    public void EndSession(Guid id)
    {
        lock(this.GetSessionLocker(id))
        {
            ASession removedSession;
            if(sessions.TryRemove(id, out removedSession))
            {
                this.CleanUpSessionRemnants(removedSession);
            }
        }
    }

    private object GetSessionLocker(Guid id)
    {
        return sessionLocks.GetOrAdd(id, x => new object());
    }

    private int DoSomethingWithSession(ASession session)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        return 1;
    }

    private void CleanUpSessionRemnants(ASession session)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

public class ASession
{
    public ASession(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few notes to address your specific questions:

> Will this perform as expected?

Only you can answer that after testing it thoroughly.

> Does sessions need to be a ConcurrentDictionary or does a regular Dictionary work fine here since I'm locking any access of the one key.

As the lock keys are different for different sessions, it is a whole lot more safe to use `ConcurrentDictionary`. That way you are at least sure that the dictionary won't screw up.

However, your approach of the `sessionLocks` map I have some doubts about. What you really seem to want to synchronize is the `return this.DoSomethingWithSession(session);` and `this.CleanUpSessionRemnants(removedSession);` calls, so I would place the lock only around those.

Speaking of placing the locks, consider placing them within the `ASession` class. In fact, I would try to move the `CleanUpSessionRemnants` and `DoSomethingWithSession` methods to the `ASession` class. If it needs the `SessionManager` object to perform its job, then pass the `SessionManager` as a parameter to the method. Right now your `ASession` seems to be only a `String`, make better use of that class. I think you created it for a reason.

> What's a good way to handle the memory leak that happens when I keep creating new locks but don't remove them for a given id after I stop using that it?

Don't create them in the first place. Really. Or at least remove them when you're done. See above. Or the code below.

```
if(sessions.TryRemove(id, out removedSession))
{
    sessionLocks.TryRemove(id);
    this.CleanUpSessionRemnants(removedSession);
}
```

Comment: Good points. This was a contrived example similar to what I'm doing, so `ASession` definitely holds more than just a name :).

Answer (score 5):

In [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44490/23788) I explain in details why *one should not throw System.Exception*. You should be throwing `InvalidOperationException` in the case of the *astronomically unlikely situation*, and probably an `ArgumentException` in the case of the non-existing session.

As far as thread safety is concerned, I don't write multithreaded code very often so I might be completely wrong, but I since `ConcurrentDictionary` is a thread-safe `IDictionary` implementation, `sessions.TryGetValue(id, out session)` is already a thread-safe call, doesn't need to be wrapped in a `lock` block.

Comment: You have many good points there, but the reason for the lock block seems to be to prevent multiple threads from simultaneously calling `DoSomethingWithSession` for the same session.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg that's right, thanks - edited out that part ;)

Comment: Good points about `System.Exception`. I wasn't really thinking much about the exceptions when putting this example together but I'll be sure to put more thought into the real version of the code.