# Looping through an Excel document in C#

Tags: c#, excel

Before looping through an Excel document using a library I found, and wanted to know how long it would take to loop through the whole thing.

There are 40k rows.

I looped through only the first 5k and it took just 2 minutes.  So, I thought, that looping through 40k would take just 16 minutes total.

However, the program has been running for over an hour now, and it still hasn't completed.

What would be slowing this thing down?  Granted, I didn't program it for high efficiency, but there must be something that is slowing this down...  Why wasn't my initial estimate accurate?

Here is my method:

```
public static void Validate(ExcelConfiguration config)
{
    var ctx = new IntakeEntities();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    HashSet<string> missingEntities = new HashSet<string>();

    Console.WriteLine("Validating...");

    using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(config.file))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[config.WorkSheet];

        // loop through each row
        for (int iRow = config.DataRowStart; iRow <= config.DataRowFinish; iRow++)
        {
            // get home country from database
            string homeCountryName = worksheet.Cell(iRow, config.HomeCountryColumnIndex).Value.Trim();
            Guid? homeCountryId = null;

            try
            {
                homeCountryId = ctx.Countries.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Name == homeCountryName).First().Id;
                //Console.WriteLine(homeCountryId + " - " + homeCountryName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("No record found for " + homeCountryName);
                missingEntities.Add(homeCountryName);
            }

            // get host country from database
            string hostCountryName = worksheet.Cell(iRow, config.HostCountryColumnIndex).Value.Trim();
            Guid? hostCountryId = null;

            try
            {
                hostCountryId = ctx.Countries.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Name == hostCountryName).First().Id;
                //Console.WriteLine(hostCountryId + " - " + hostCountryName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("No record found for " + hostCountryName);
                missingEntities.Add(hostCountryName);
            }

            if (config.HomeLocationColumnIndex != null && config.HostLocationColumnIndex != null)
            {
                // get home country from database
                string homeLocationName = worksheet.Cell(iRow, (int)config.HomeLocationColumnIndex).Value.Trim();
                Guid? homeLocationId = null;

                try
                {
                    homeLocationId = ctx.Locations.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Name == homeLocationName).First().Id;
                    //Console.WriteLine(homeCountryId + " - " + homeCountryName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("No record found for " + homeLocationName);
                    missingEntities.Add(homeLocationName);
                }

                // get host country from database
                string hostLocationName = worksheet.Cell(iRow, (int)config.HostLocationColumnIndex).Value.Trim();
                Guid? hostLocationId = null;

                try
                {
                    hostLocationId = ctx.Locations.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Name == hostLocationName).First().Id;
                    //Console.WriteLine(hostCountryId + " - " + hostCountryName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("No record found for " + hostLocationName);
                    missingEntities.Add(hostLocationName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Validation complete...");
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0} minutes", sw.Elapsed.Minutes);

    Console.WriteLine("No records found for:");
    foreach (string entity in missingEntities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entity);
    }
}
```

Here is the accompanying object:

```
public class ExcelConfiguration
{
    public FileInfo file { get; set; }
    public int HomeCountryColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public int HostCountryColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public int? HomeLocationColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public int? HostLocationColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public int WorkSheet { get; set; }
    public int DataRowStart { get; set; }
    public int DataRowFinish { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With appreciation for the answers and sound advice provided here, I have concluded that the real source of the issue was not my improper use of `try/catch` nor `FirstOrDefault()` or any of that, but rather, it was the Excel package.

To fix this, the only solution would be to convert the Excel into a CSV which would allow for faster access of data.  Instead of that, I just chose to modify my `DataRowStart` and `DataRowFinish` by shrinking the window so it wouldn't get bogged down.

**Update:**

After converting my document to CSV and using [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) and [changing the runtime configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662102/1477388) of my `DbContext` like so:

```
yourContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
yourContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

...  I was able to validate and insert all 40k records in under 15 minutes; whereas, before it would've taken hours (if it finished at all).  I think most of the benefit actually came from the `DbContext` change.  That alone was a major improvement.

Comment: did you try to fix the `try catch` usage?

Comment: Yes, it helped some, but according to the built in Profiler in VS 2012, most of the time was taken up by the reads to the Excel document, not by database calls or try/catch, etc.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me; as I explained in [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46960/23788) the real cost of throwing+catching exceptions is often over-estimated. I thought 40K iterations would actually make a difference, but I under-estimated the cost of COM interop: *"Then I'd try to reduce the number of Excel worksheet reads, if that's at all possible."* - that should have been my first advice ;)

Comment: glad you got it going.

Comment: Thanks.  I posted an update since I thought it was really cool.  By making those changes, I was able to complete the entire operation in under 15 mins.

Comment: feel free to accept any useful answer, doing that will generate a whole 17 points on the site (assuming you're not accepting *your own* answer, which you can of course) :)

Answer (score 6):

- Have performance issues? Use a profiler. (There is a built-in in certain versions of Visual Studio and a bunch of third-party tools, with evaluation times). Find out what is taking time and we can give you an advice for optimization after that.
- As already mentioned, do not use exceptions for normal program flow. Use `FirstOrDefault()` method instead of `First()` so you don't get an exception for missing items.
- If you want a guess - you have 4 database queries per row => 160k queries. Either adjust database indexes, or load whole tables into `Dictionary<>` if they are small enough (Countries table, for example, is probably small)

Comment: +1 Good call, caching the smaller data sets locally, but `.FirstOrDefault().Id` will still potentially throw a `NullReferenceException` - the trick is to do `.FirstOrDefault()` (or `.SingleOrDefault()`), *check if we have a result*, and then if we do, get the `.Id`.

Comment: Yep, of course I meant FirstOrDefault()->Null check-> .Id

Comment: +1, Very good advice here.  The only thing is, I already tried loading the entire tables into a local cache both the method you described and using `.Load()` of Linq.  I used the `StopWatch()` to compare and actually, both methods were slower than the one I am using now.  Do you have a recommended implementation for this?

Comment: +1 for use a profiler. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/ is the best by leaps and bounds, in my opinion.

Comment: Another question:  After profiling using the VS2012 Analyzer, it tells me that most of the problem is the accessing of the Excel Cells.  But, how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> public static void Validate(ExcelConfiguration config)
> ```

I wouldn't make this a `static` method, but without knowing more about your project it's just a nitpick. The name is highly misleading though. Without looking at the code, one would expect that the method *validates the passed `ExcelConfiguration`* - I don't know, maybe check that `DataRowStart` is within a specific range (like, a positive number), and that the `File` (capital F) exists... wait, you've got a `FileInfo` there, that's rather surprising. Also `WorkSheet` should be called `WorksheetIndex`... but I digress.

> ```
> var ctx = new IntakeEntities();
> ```

I like that you're using `var`. However if this `IntakeEntities` is what I think it is, it's derived from `DbContext` and implements `IDisposable`, and should be wrapped in a `using` block.

> ```
> Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
> ```

Why not use `var` again? Be consistent! That said, you're doing the right thing - `StopWatch` is how you should time execution... but that stop watch should be in the method's calling code, starting just before the method call and stopping right after it returns. Writing the results to the console doesn't belong in that method either.

---

Are you *actually* catching many exceptions? Are exceptions *exceptional* or just a "neat" way of adding items to `missingEntities`?

I think you're misusing exceptions, because if you didn't systematically tried to get the `Id` property of an object that's potentially `null`, you could do a null check instead, and to everything without catching a `NullReferenceException` - use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Where` and then `First`, it makes it clearer that you're expecting zero or one values:

```
var homeCountry = ctx.Countries.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == homeCountryName);
homeCountryId = (homeCountry == null ? 0 : homeCountry.Id);

if (homeCountryId == 0)
{
    missingEntities.Add(homeCountryName);
}
```

Throwing and catching exceptions without a real reason, in a loop, 40K times, can slow things down if half the iterations throw 2-3 exceptions. I'd try to eliminate the throwing and catching first, see what I get.

Then I'd try to reduce the number of Excel worksheet reads, if that's at all possible.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I have confidence in your answer.  I will try it soon.

Comment: I tend to disagree with the use of `var` for known types: from c#3.0 language reference... "Overuse of var can make source code less readable for others. It is recommended to use var only when it is necessary, that is, when the variable will be used to store an anonymous type or a collection of anonymous types."

Comment: Also while using `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Foo");` might look neater, using `Where(x => x.Name == "Foo").FirstOrDefault();` is actually quicker. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663897/why-is-linq-wherepredicate-first-faster-than-firstpredicate). A micro optimisation but on a 40k loop with 4 calls might make a difference.

Comment: @NickWilliams I tend to disagree with what's considered "overuse" of `var`. I don't see how cutting redundant clutter reduces readability, and using `var` or not boils down to personal preference - in my answer I only recommended consistency in its usage.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I would always follow the language reference on these matters if trying to suggest best practise. Most (not all) code I have seen where `var` is used for every variable ends up with longer, more Hungarian style variable names. The main thing is to be consistent of course.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that people are touching on but not saying outright is the fact that Exception handling takes a lot of processing power away from what you want going on,  just the operation of catching the exception itself is what is slowing you down.

you are using `Catch` statements inappropriately.

if you know the exception then you need to code so that it won't happen.

a try catch statement is more for the unexpected errors.

like @Mat's Mug was saying, check to see if it exists, if it doesn't add it to the missing entities collection, don't let it throw an error.

---

as far as your estimate being wrong.

> I looped through only the first 5k and it took just 2 minutes. So, I thought, that looping through 40k would take just 16 minutes total.

the issue with this is that for the first 5k records there is (theoretically) nothing being held in memory or processor cache or heap, so when the next 5k records go through there is stuff being processed already these 5k records have to wait in line, stack another 5k on top of that, now the processor is getting warm which slows it down a little bit, it's trying to multi thread information is getting backed up.  it's like having 40 tabs open on a browser, I am done with the first 35 but have things running super slow on the remaining 5 it's slow because there is stuff in the way sitting in the receiving and sending area.

okay so I BS'd my way through that, but you get the point right?